# Can you still use x.org in 21.04?

Tags: xorg, wayland, 21.04

I installed 21.04 on my laptop to try it out, and now it comes with wayland as the default.

However, I'm noticing some issues with my digital drawing tablet and I wanted to switch to x.org to see if it is related to that, only that I can't see the little cogwheel that would let me do so on the log in screen.

Am I missing a step, is it possible to do it still?

EDIT: I may be silly but it finally showed up, I'll just close the post but it appears after clicking on an user and not before as I thought it might.

Comment: Yes, in fact on a number of boxes (with specific hardware) Ubuntu 21.04 will default to using Xorg...   in QA-testing (before release) I found more of my boxes defaulted to Xorg than used Wayland by default (I used 15 boxes testing *hirsute*).  Select it at login

Comment: @guiverc  The OP seems to be saying he cannot find it on his login screen.  Says he does not see the usual cogwheel to change.

Comment: Thanks @crip659 , yeah I see the issue now (re-created it on *live*).. alas I don't have a pure ubuntu *hirsute* install anymore (i QA-tested xubuntu after ubu) & my own installs use `sddm`  (so at last resort switching DM works)

Comment: Show me `grep -i wayland /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.

Answer (score 6):

I'll answer myself just to leave it on the record.
It was simply that the cogwheel appeared after clicking on a user and not the user selection menu.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be similar in 20.04's GDM login screen too: the cogwheel with the display manager choices shows up only as the cursor is placed into the password field. Either a bug, or yet another specimen from the rich collection of misguidedly reasoned "gnome UX features".